# Перемещение Thumb в указанное место Slider

Tags: wpf, xaml

Здравствуйте, появилось проблема при перемещении Thumb в указанное место. Какими свойствами нужно воспользоваться, чтобы стало возможно перемещаться к указанному участку Slider'a? Как пример: используя стандартный Slider.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используя только одно свойство `IsMoveToPointEnabled="True"`, можно перемещать `Thumb` указывая любое место в `Slider`.

```
     <StackPanel Margin="5" Grid.Row="1">
        <TextBox Text="{Binding ElementName=slValue, Path=Value, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" DockPanel.Dock="Right" TextAlignment="Right" Width="40"/>
        <Slider Maximum="100" IsMoveToPointEnabled="True" TickPlacement="BottomRight" TickFrequency="1" IsSnapToTickEnabled="True" Name="slValue"/>
     </StackPanel>
```